# Propel Criteria::setLimit() like LIMIT 0,6

Tags: mysql, symfony1, symfony-1.4, propel

In my query using Symfony 1.4/Propel 1.4, for pagination purpose, I need to set limit like

```
Page1: LIMIT 0,6
Page2: LIMIT 6,6
Page3: LIMIT 12,6
.... & so on
```

I try

```
$c->setLimit(6);
```

Which is generating

```
LIMIT 6
```

I didn't find setLimit methods with two parameters or similar function to set starting limit too. This is very common operation & I'm sure must be available in Propel but I'm unable to figure it out till now.

Can someone please suggest how set required limit **(LIMIT 0,6)**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use `limit()` and `offset()`, described [here](http://www.propelorm.org/reference/model-criteria.html#more_complex_queries).

For

```
LIMIT 12,6
```

use (if you are using the 1.6 ModelCriteria)

```
$c->limit(6);
$c->offset(12);
```

and if you use old criteria:

```
$c->setLimit(12);
$c->setOffset(12);
```

By the way, why do you build your own pager? Symfony profive a sfPager (generic) and also a [sfPropelPager](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfPropelPager) which handle that pretty well (even if you use a custom criteria, you can defined it using `setCriteria()`).

Comment: Thanks @j0k. Well I never used sfPropelPager. Thanks for that info. I'll definitely look into it after code freeze of first version of product next week and also switch to latest version of propel.